# C# Insert Multiple Records into Database Table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have a role based permission login which determines the menu options available to the logged in user.

Currently when saving a new Role I make use of a stored procedure.

```cs
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertRole", con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleName", roleNameTB.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", descriptionTB.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", LoggedInUser.UserName);
```

The above is obviously not the full code. Regardless, this part of the process works.

However, I now need to add the menu items to the permissions table in order to enable or disable the menu items for that specific role.

I currently only need to insert 4 new lines/records (the current menu items created so far, shouldn't be more than about 20 in total). I would prefer it being inserted directly after the new ROLE has been inserted into the roles database or it can be inserted on the Permissions page by clicking the insert button.

```cs
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleId", combobox.selectedvalue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubMenuId", 1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", 0);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleId", combobox.selectedvalue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubMenuId", 2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", 0);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleId", combobox.selectedvalue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubMenuId", 3);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", 0);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleId", combobox.selectedvalue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubMenuId", 4);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", 0);
```

I'm aware the above is wrong, but it's just there to show you the records I need inserted. The `RoleId` would always be the NEWLY created role. I do have `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` set in the `InsertRole` procedure.

I'm not to well versed with SQL in this sense, so I don't know what the best way to achieve this would be.

Any guidance would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can get what you need from this related post: [pass-multiple-values-to-stored-procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905815/pass-multiple-values-to-stored-procedure)

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use case for a table-valued parameter.

Comment: Might want to take a peek at this also before you keep using AddWithValue. https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: Thank you guys. I appreacite the feedback. I'll have a look at both. I know it's 2 months late but unfortunately life happened and this had to go on the back burner till now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use ORMs like Entity Framework instead of ADO.NET.
But regarding your question there are some options like:

- Adding an output parameter to InsertRole procedure and getting the value in your c# code.
- Selecting the inserted RoleId at the end of procedure and using a DataReader or DataAdapter to filling the result in a DataTable and using the returned value.
- Passing SubMenu list as a json parameter to InsertRole procedure or create a new procedure (InsertSubMenu) to do bulk insert. I suggest you to use Json/Xml parameter instead of table-valued parameters if the columns are not finalized or using SQL bulk copy library.
- ...

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. I know it's 2 months late but life happened unfortunately and this had to go on the back burner but I'm getting back in the saddle so to speak.